# Can I receive the money for my google playstore app in paypal?

Tags: android, paypal

I'm trying to sell an app in the google playstore, however, I've been said that I can't receive payments from paypal for an app in the store, I'm from El Salvador, Central America, and I'd like to know if this is possible, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not you need google wallet and the `Google wallet` works directly to your bank account or visa or mastercard or any other type ..
the issue that as long as i know that google wallet does not support paypal and be the way
google wallet is safe and fast

Comment: It seems that my country is not eligible for a merchant account even if Google Wallet is going to be used, now that's a shame...no workarounds right? thanks!